# meteor collection helpers vs orm

Tags: javascript, typescript, meteor

I would like some kind of Model for my Meteor collections. The two options I could  find for this would be to use collection helpers:

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection('users')
Users.helpers({
  fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
  }
})
```

or to map the returned objects to class instances:

```
 class UserCollection extends Mongo.Collection {
    fetch() : User[] {
        return super.fetch().map(user => new User(user))
    }
}

let users = new UserCollection('users')

class User {
    collection: Mongo.Collection
    _id: string
    firstName: string
    lastName: string

    constructor({firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this.firstName = firstName
        this.lastName = lastName
        this.collection = users
    }

    get fullname () {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
    }
    save () {
        if(this._id) {
            this.collection.update({ $set: { ...this }})
        }
        else {
            this.collection.insert({...this})
        }
    }
}
```

Which variant is preferable? I like B more, but rarely found any examples using it.

Comment: I think this is an area where it's up to individual tastes, and most of the community is using the collection directly, so doesn't have a best practice for Model construction

Comment: See https://dweldon.silvrback.com/models which is a great write-up on how to do this. Also https://www.okgrow.com/posts/meteor-transform